# Storing keys on user devices

Tags: security, cryptography, raspberry-pi

So say I have some random hardware box I send out to customers. In this case, it'll be a Raspberry Pi inside. I want that Pi to be able to connect securely to a web service that is only accessible by the Raspberries that I have. Each Pi contains its own key that it uses to verify with the web service.

In this case, think of the RPi as any other embedded user device.  It boots up and just does its own thing to call home.  The user doesn't enter anything.

Is there any way to securely store these keys on the Pi?  I wouldn't want people to be able to connect to the web service and verify with some keys they read off the SD card.

I'm used to dealing with this in the context of a user providing access to the keys with a keyring or something like that, but I'm not sure how you could store keys on an embedded device that requires there be no user input without using some ridiculous secure bootloader scheme or something like that.

Comment: There are hardware security modules, smart cards and other such devices that are difficult to tamper with, but they are not completely safe either. It depends on how sophisticated your adversaries are and what the risks are.

Answer (score 0):

If the key must be stored on the Pi somehow, and anything on the Pi can be read, you're out of luck. Any sort of key or algorithm you might use to come up with something to transmit can be copied and faked by a third party.

Here is a post with some ideas of how to try to secure a Pi running Linux: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1250

Comment: I'm more looking for how to verify that the PI is one produced by me.  Pi connects to my service, and I ask for some info from it to verify that it is indeed one that I produced. Is there a shceme that I can use with the pi that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Well, the obvious choice is to use public-key encryption, but that requires storing either a public or private key on the Pi. If the Pi isn't secure, that isn't really an option. You could store the public key on the Pi and send it to the server, which would recognize that key, but then you risk someone discovering the public key in the process.